# Calculate % based on matching column values

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm a bit stumped on how to achieve something in SQL - might be missing something obvious. I am wanting to calculate the % a value in a column contributes to the total of this column, but that matches to several other column criteria

I have some data that looks something like this:

| Country | Date | Cust | Sector | Type | Total | % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| US | 201902 | ABCD | ABC-DEF | OTHER | 312 | ? |
| DE | 201902 | ABCD | ABC-DEF | OTHER | 3987 | ? |
| US | 201902 | ABCD | DEF-GHI | MAIN | 122 | ? |

I would like to calculate a % for each row that is the percentage that the country's total is of the total - where Date, Cust, Sector and Type match.

So for example, row 1, US % would be 0.0725 ( 312 / (312+3987) ), and row 2 would be 0.9275   , as date, cust, sector and type match, but wouldn't include 122 (row 3) in the calculation as sector and type doesn't match.

I can calculate it using the sum of total for all of the data returned (below code, simplified) - but not sure how to break it down to the totals matching records of several columns only

```
SELECT COUNTRY, DATE, CUST, SECTOR, TYPE, SUM(TOTAL), SUM(TOTAL) / (SELECT SUM(TOTAL) FROM Data) as PERCENT
FROM Data
GROUP BY COUNTRY, DATE, CUST, SECTOR, TYPE;
```

Hope that makes sense - any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Grouping_Sets()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/group-by-grouping-sets.html) is also quite powerful - essentially does any->all combos without tonnes of code.

[image]

```
with data(Country, Date, Cust, Sector, Type, Total) as (
select * from values 
    ('US', '201902', 'ABCD', 'ABC-DEF', 'OTHER', 212),
    ('US', '201902', 'ABCD', 'ABC-DEF', 'OTHER', 100),
    ('DE', '201902', 'ABCD', 'ABC-DEF', 'OTHER', 3987),
    ('US', '201902', 'ABCD', 'DEF-GHI', 'MAIN', 122)
)

select sum(Total) Total , Country ,type, Cust, Sector, Date from data group by 
grouping sets (Country ,type, Cust, Sector, Date) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

So you can use a WINDOW FRAME version of sum like so:

```
with data(Country, Date, Cust, Sector, Type, Total) as (
    select * from values 
        ('US', '201902', 'ABCD', 'ABC-DEF', 'OTHER', 312),
        ('DE', '201902', 'ABCD', 'ABC-DEF', 'OTHER', 3987),
        ('US', '201902', 'ABCD', 'DEF-GHI', 'MAIN', 122)
)
select d.*
    ,round(100 * total / sum(total) over(partition by d.date, d.cust, d.sector, d.type),2) as percent
from data as d
```

gives:

| COUNTRY | DATE | CUST | SECTOR | TYPE | TOTAL | PERCENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| US | 201902 | ABCD | ABC-DEF | OTHER | 312 | 7.26 |
| DE | 201902 | ABCD | ABC-DEF | OTHER | 3,987 | 92.74 |
| US | 201902 | ABCD | DEF-GHI | MAIN | 122 | 100 |

but if you have many values you want to roll-up, [RATIO_TO_REPORT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/ratio_to_report.html) can help do some of the lifting:

```
with data(Country, Date, Cust, Sector, Type, Total) as (
    select * from values 
        ('US', '201902', 'ABCD', 'ABC-DEF', 'OTHER', 212),
        ('US', '201902', 'ABCD', 'ABC-DEF', 'OTHER', 100),
        ('DE', '201902', 'ABCD', 'ABC-DEF', 'OTHER', 3987),
        ('US', '201902', 'ABCD', 'DEF-GHI', 'MAIN', 122)
)
select d.country, d.Date, d.Cust, d.Sector, d.Type
    ,sum(total) as part
    ,ratio_to_report(part) over( partition by d.date, d.cust, d.sector, d.type) 
from data as d
group by 1,2,3,4,5
```

| COUNTRY | DATE | CUST | SECTOR | TYPE | PART | PERCENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| US | 201902 | ABCD | ABC-DEF | OTHER | 312 | 0.072575 |
| DE | 201902 | ABCD | ABC-DEF | OTHER | 3,987 | 0.927425 |
| US | 201902 | ABCD | DEF-GHI | MAIN | 122 | 1 |

Comment: Thank you! That looks like it will do the trick and exactly what I need. 

Probably a silly question but for the values section 
ie.  ('US', '201902', 'ABCD', 'ABC-DEF', 'OTHER', 212)

Would I need to enter these all manually or can I pull it via another statement? There are thousands of rows

Thanks again

Comment: I just put them into a CTE to avoid having to create table to them delete later... just use the `select d.country, d.Date, d.Cust, d.Sector, d.Type
    ,sum(total) as part
    ,ratio_to_report(part) over( partition by d.date, d.cust, d.sector, d.type) 
from data as d
group by 1,2,3,4,5` part.

Comment: Thank you - that's done the trick